# Is there a way to give ElasticSearch "default/override" values?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a hypothetical ElasticSearch index containing information about users configuration on various systems. All the systems use the same fields/values for their configuration, a user has a set of default config options that will be used if no custom options are set for a system, and to reduce space I want to avoid repeating the default values.

Consider this example ElasticSearch document source object:

```
{
  userId: 12345,
  default: {
    columnWidth: 250,
    rowHeight: 100,
    pageSize: 50,
    autoRefreshInterval: 60
  },
  systems: {
    systemA: {
      autoRefreshInterval: 0,
      pageSize: 500
    },
    systemB: {
      columnWidth: 400
    }
  }
}
```

Fetching this document by userID is easy enough, but what if I want to do some queries about how the users use the systems? If I wanted to find all users that don't use auto-refresh for systemB I would have to query `systems.systemB.autoRefreshInterval:0 OR (_missing_:systems.systemB.autoRefreshInterval AND default.autoRefreshInterval:0)` which is verbose and would be a nightmare to query more than one attribute at a time. Is there any way to configure the index mapping to set default or fallback fields that will allow me to simply query `systems.systemB.autoRefreshInterval:0` and get this document back because the default value is set correctly?

Comment: Firstly, do you know that you can use [bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) ES query and send it with POST? (You provide example with GET request). Secondly, I would suggest to transform data in a way it is easily queryable (e.g. fill in defaults before inserting the document).

Comment: Firstly, yes I do know that a DSL bool queries are issued via POST, however my example doesn't specify a protocol nor is it relevant to what I'm asking. I would like to be able to do this via Query String Queries and the example queries I provided are statements which might appear in those query strings. Secondly, I'm aware that I can fill in the defaults at indexing time, the point of asking this question was to see if there's a way of not doing that (see question above "and to reduce space I want to avoid repeating the default values").

Answer (score 0):

After lots of reading docs, forums, and asking around I've determined that this is not a use case that ElasticSearch supports. In order to accomplish this I'll either have to deal with the additional storage space and copy the default values up to the individual systems or write some really verbose and ugly queries.